# How to install and configure Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: release-freya, google-chrome

I have "elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya 32-bit". I tried to deploy Chrome Remote Desktop according to [this manual](http://www.elementarynow.com/chrome-remote-desktop/), but unsuccessfully. I can connect just using green "Share" button and one-time access code, but I cannot connect via "My Computers" section in Chrome Remote Desktop.

If I try to connect, I receive the following error:

> "The remote computer is not responding to connection requests. Please verify that it is online and try again."

Can you help me?

More details:
File `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` contains
`exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=pantheon"`

Comment: Does the Pantheon session work as expected when you connect with the green "Share" button? Actually I ask this because I could not get pantheon working (elementary OS 0.4 Loki)  in Chrome Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the Chromium ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647700), the solution is to use root when setting up CRD.